# Вывод в QPlainTextEdit сообщения из модуля logging. Логирование

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, логирование, qplaintextedit

Как сделать так, чтобы сообщения из модуля *logging* 
выходили в окне `QPlainTextEdit`?

Желательно показать на моём примере как *из потока* вывести сообщение по завершению действия функции, так и *без потока*. 
По сути логирование программы.

```py
import sys
import logging
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(316, 324)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 240, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 291, 131))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 180, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.plainTextEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse) # Делает QPlainTextEdit только для вывода

        self.thread = WorkThread()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)

        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
        logging.info(u'This is an info message')

    def func1(self):
        # Создаем поток
        self.thread.start()


class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ''' Потоковая задача '''
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):     # После окончания работы этой фукции в потоке,вывести сообщение от модуля logging в QPlainTextEdit
        for i in range(10):
            self.msleep(200)
            print(i)
            self.threadSignal.emit(i)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()          # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import logging
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(316, 324)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 240, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 291, 131))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 180, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


# +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = parent.plainTextEdit 
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
        logTextBox.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(logTextBox)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      

        # Делает QPlainTextEdit только для вывода
        self.plainTextEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse) 

        self.thread = WorkThread()
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.func2)                                      # +++
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)      

        logging.debug("Это сообщение об отладке")
        logging.info(u'This is an info message')

    def func1(self):
        # Создаем поток
        self.thread.start()

    def func2(self, value):                                                               # +++
        logging.info("Передано из потока -> {}".format(value))                            # +++


class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ''' Потоковая задача '''
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):     
        for i in range(10):
            self.msleep(200)
#            print(i)
            self.threadSignal.emit(i)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()                   
    window.show()                           
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> каким образом можно вывести сообщение по завершению действия в потоке?

```
import logging
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 324)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 240, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 370, 131))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 180, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = parent.plainTextEdit 
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
        logTextBox.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(logTextBox)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)                              # +++
        layout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton) 

        self.plainTextEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse) 
        self.thread = WorkThread()
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.func2)                           

        self.thread.finishSignal.connect(self.func3)                                     # +++

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)      

        logging.debug("Это сообщение об отладке")
        logging.info('This is an info message')

    def func1(self):
        # Создаем поток
        self.thread.start()

    def func2(self, value):                                                               
        logging.info("Передано из потока -> {}".format(value))         

    def func3(self):                                                               
        logging.info("Программа зевершена")          


class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ''' Потоковая задача '''
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    finishSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()                                                    # +++

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):     
        for i in range(10):
            self.msleep(200)
            self.threadSignal.emit(i)

        self.finishSignal.emit()                                                         # +++

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()                   
    window.show()                           
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз)

Comment: Хорошо,но каким образом можно вывести сообщение по завершению действия в потоке?Если вставить logging.info("Программа зевершена") в метод run результата не даёт.Допустим в методе run выполняются определённые действия и мне нужно периодически выводить сообщения.Без метода run всё вроде бы понятно,мы вставляем logging.info("") в куски кода и всё.А тут как?

Comment: @Leon я добавил пример

Comment: Благодарствую.)

Comment: @Leon Механизм сигналов и слотов является центральной особенностью Qt. Рекомендую внимательно изучить раздел https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: С английским трудно,нашёл книгу Дронов python и Pyqt5,буду читать.Там вроде есть про это.

Comment: @Leon Google Переводчик вам в помощь :) https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=hello%20world